# Showing that a finite simple graph has at least two vertices with the same degree

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that a finite simple graph has at least two vertices with the same degree.

This is the approach I took to solve this problem. I have read similar posts, but they all make reference to the pigeonhole principle and since I don't use that directly, I was wondering if anyone could tell me if this is a good approach for the problem.

> I suppose that, as a contradiction, there existed no vertices with the same degree. Then, that would imply we would have a vertex of degree $0$, another of degree $1$, another of degree $2$ and so on. But then, this would imply that our graph would need to be infinite, contradicting the finiteness premise. Therefore, we have a contradiction and the graph should have at least $2$ vertices with the same degree.

Comment: How does "our graph would need to be finite" contradict the finiteness premise? Was finite a typo for "infinite"?

Comment: Suppose the simple graph has five vertices, a finite number. Possible degrees for a vertex ae $0,1,2,3,4.$ If no two vertices have the same degree, then there is a vertex of degree $0,$ another of degree $1,$ another of degree $2,$ another of degree $3,$ and another of degree $4.$ How does that "contradict the finiteness premise"? We do get a contradiction from that, but you haven't put your finger on it.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a typo. In the example you mention, would the contradiction be that the graph is no longer simple?

Comment: @urpi, no. You kinda *have to* use the pigeonhole principal to neatly arrive at a contradiction here.

Comment: Hint: the contradiction is that a simple graph of order $5$ can't have both a vertex of degree $4$ and a vertex of degree $0.$ Why is that?